# Attribute names of objects

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Where are the `$_.` attribute names when iterating listed?
For example `$_.Name` when iterating over `Get-Process`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see the object types and the type's properties, methods and events by piping the output into `Get-Member`. For `Get-Process`:

```
Get-Process| Get-Member
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's what you want, but you can try this :

Get-process | get-member

to know what properties and functions are available on your objects...